# How do I initialize a custom view controller from within the class itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to use the third-party library [MBPullDownController](https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController) to make something like the sliding up panel in the Google Maps app.

Here's the sample code from the library:

```
UITableViewController *front = [[UITableViewController new];
UIViewController *back = [[UIViewController new];
MBPullDownController *pullDownController = [[MBPullDownController alloc] initWithFrontController:front backController:back];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pullDownController animated:NO];
```

That works fine when navigating to it from a different view controller. However my maps controller has four or five other view controllers leading to it directly, so I'm trying to do the initialization from the maps controller itself.

I've tried making my view controller a subclass of MBPullDownController and trying to initialize it in the `initUsingCoder:` method as follows:

`MapViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "MBPullDownController.h"
....

@interface MapViewController : MBPullDownController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
....
@end
```

`MapViewController.m`

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "LocationUtility.h"
#import "MBPullDownController.h"
...

@interface MapViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

@implementation MapViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView;
    NSMutableDictionary *markers;
}

@implementation MapViewController {
GMSMapView *mapView;
NSMutableDictionary *markers;
UITableViewController *front;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        front = [UITableViewController new];
        self = (MapViewController *)[[MBPullDownController alloc]initWithFrontController:front backController:self ];
    }
    return self;
}
....
```

I'm getting the warning `'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'`, obviously because `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]` is getting replaced by `self = (MapViewController *)[[MBPullDownController alloc]initWithFrontController:front backController:self ];`

How do I do initialize the view controller as an MBPullDownController from itself properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution in the middle of writing the question, but I figured I'll keep it up to help other people with the same problem since the answer wasn't easy to find.

The solution is to use the `-(id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method, which "allows you to substitute another object in place of the object that was decoded" [(source)](http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/03/26/reusable/).

```
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self) {
        front = [UITableViewController new];
        self = (MapViewController *)[[MBPullDownController alloc]initWithFrontController:front backController:self ];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to init an instance of MBPullDownController with the initializer initWithFrontController.. instead of initWithCoder, which is the one iOS forced you to call when instantiating objects from nibs.

The library should have another method named initWithCoder: andFrontController: andBackController, that takes care of calling super plus sets the child controllers correctly.

However, since that isn't provided, it seems that the creator did both properties frontController, and backController public. This usually (if he did it well) means that you can feel free set those properties after calling the initializr. So I would try:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.frontController = [UITableViewController new];
        self.backController = self;
    }
    return self;  
}
```

If this doesnt work, you should create an Issue in github and tell the creator to add the initWithCoder initializer, and keep with your solution with awakeAfterUsingCoder

Comment: That gives me `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'`. Is there any kind of performance advantage to doing it in the initWithCoder method instead of the awakeAfterUsingCoder method?

Comment: Isn't it weird that you are adding self as backController? I don't think that the library is meant to work like that. The error you are getting is because calling self.backController = self is adding self as a subview of self, which breaks. 

You probably need to have controller A (MBPullDownController) have B as back and C as front.

Comment: I think you're right that's it's not intended to be used this way. However I'm not quite sure how to do that without breaking the navigation or having to write repetitive code every time I try to navigate to it. I'll give it a try though.